# Select segment button while vertical scrolling in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

{{menu?.title}}

```
<ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="12">
    <div class="menu" *ngFor="let menu of menuList | async" [id]="menu.title" (reachedIndex)="onReachedIndex($event)">
      <div #scrolledToElement class="main-menu" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+menu.img+')'}">
        <div class="bg-black"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="heading ion-text-center">
            <ion-text color="light">{{menu.title}}</ion-text>
          </div>
          <div class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-text color="light">
              {{menu.description}}
            </ion-text>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-list" *ngFor="let item of menu.items" (click)="gotoPage(item.id)">
        <div class="item-detai">
          <div class="f-w-b label">
            <ion-text color="dark">{{item.title}}</ion-text>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ion-text color="medium">{{item.description}}</ion-text>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-des">
          <div class="discount-item" *ngIf="item.discount">
            <ion-text>{{item.discount}}% Rabatt</ion-text>
          </div>
          <div class="icon-list" *ngIf="item.icons && item.icons.length">
            <ion-icon color="danger" *ngFor="let icon of item.icons" [name]="icon"></ion-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            {{item.price | currency : 'CHF ': 'code'}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
```

TS file

```
clickSegment(menu){
 this.segment = 'menu'+menu.id;
 const offset = document.getElementById(menu.title).offsetTop;
 this.content.scrollToPoint(0,offset,400)
}
```

When I click on the segment button screen show to the targeted element. But I need this when I scroll the screen the segment button should select auto.

[image: Menu should select auto while scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to scroll events and select needed segments in this way:

home.page.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment">
            <ion-segment-button value="segment1" (click)="scrollToSegment(1)">
                <ion-label>Segment 1</ion-label>
            </ion-segment-button>

            <ion-segment-button value="segment2" (click)="scrollToSegment(2)">
                <ion-label>Segment 2</ion-label>
            </ion-segment-button>

            <ion-segment-button value="segment3" (click)="scrollToSegment(3)">
                <ion-label>Segment 3</ion-label>
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <div #section1 class="section-1"></div>
    <div #section2 class="section-2"></div>
    <div #section3 class="section-3"></div>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.scss

```
.section-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: red;
}

.section-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: green;
}

.section-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background: blue;
}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
    @ViewChild('section1') section1: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('section2') section2: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('section3') section3: ElementRef;

    selectedSegment: 'segment1' | 'segment2' | 'segment3' = 'segment1';

    scrollToSegment(id: number) {
        this.content.scrollToPoint(0, this[`section${id}`].nativeElement.offsetTop, 500);
    }

    onScroll(ev: CustomEvent) {
        const threshold = -200;
        const point1 = this.section1.nativeElement.offsetTop - ev.detail.scrollTop;
        const point2 = this.section2.nativeElement.offsetTop - ev.detail.scrollTop;

        if (point1 > threshold) {
            this.selectedSegment = 'segment1';
        } else if (point2 > threshold) {
            this.selectedSegment = 'segment2';
        } else {
            this.selectedSegment = 'segment3';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answers. But it's not work in my case. thanks for your struggle. But I really get clue from this answer.